# Keyboard and trackpad not working on a 2015 MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, keyboard, trackpad

I have a MacBook Pro (Early 2015) and roughly 2 years ago, the keyboard and the trackpad stopped working. So I stopped using it.

Two days ago, I had the idea to try it again. And it did still not work.

Then, I tried to install [Pop!_OS](https://pop.system76.com/) via USB and I was able to use my keyboard and my trackpad already during the installation process.

A friend of mine has sent me a USB flash drive with macOS Catalina on it to try a fresh installation. However, the problems are back and while trying to install macOS, I am again, unable to use my keyboard nor the trackpad.

What could be the problem here? The hardware itself works fine for obvious reasons.

Comment: If you boot into Recovery (`Cmd-R` while booting), does the track pad and keyboard work?

Comment: Just with external keyboard.

Comment: After you get into recovery, do they work?

Comment: No, they don't.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue is not with the macOS itself but rather due to the hardware controller inside your computer. In such cases, you should reset the System Management Controller (SMC) by following the steps below:

1. Turn off your computer
2. Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>) + Power Button for 10 seconds
3. Release the keys and let the macOS boot up